# RStudio hangs for a specific project. What file needs to be changed?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-raster

I have a project that I've been working on for several months without a problem. Yesterday I tried to profile a bit of code using the raster package that was taking a very long time to run. I left it running overnight and found RStudio unresponsive in the morning. Now when I open that project, I can't do anything except to force quit RStudio. Other projects appear to work fine.

I suspect something bad is stored in the file(s) that remembers where I was. Is there one or more that I can delete and regain control of the project. Candidates in the project folder would seem to be one or more items in the .Rproj.user directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a tip on the RStudio [website](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218730228-Resetting-a-user-s-state-on-RStudio-Server). In a terminal, navigate to the project directory and rename `.Rproj.user` to something different. I used this command - `mv .Rproj.user .Rproj.user_old`. This keeps the user-specific information around in case you want to go back to it.